# Receiving this error? Error TS2304: Cannot find name

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run my unit test for my angular application but when running 'ng test' I receive the following error: "Error TS2304: Cannot find name.." Running 'ng serve' works perfectly fine.

I have tried this guide to no avail https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update#one-tsconfig-per-app.

tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json file

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json file

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I expect to see Karma being loaded and run showing my tests passing since it is the default test. Instead the errors pop up saying Cannot find 'name here'

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "*****",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run ******"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "7.1.1",
    "bloomreach-experience-ng-sdk": "^0.1.1-rc1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonpointer": "^4.0.1",
    "path-to-regexp": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.12",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your `package.json` look?

Comment: @nircraft I also tried taking out jasmine in hopes of something happening in the tsconfig.spec file but that didn't work so I put it back in. I added what my package.json file looks like up top

Comment: Have you tried `npm test`?

Comment: @nircraft Yes it comes up with the same error message unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Make sure for any models or classes you are trying to use are properly exported for other files.

e.g. Do this

```
export interface FooModel {
   someProp: string;
}
```

Instead of:

```
interface FooModel {
   someProp: string;
}
```

When serving the application, it won't check for cases of using an interface in another file that hasn't been exported.  However, when compiling for ng test, it will check.